# Invalid matrix error when trying to extract hand contours from a depth image

Tags: c++, opencv, openni

I'm using OpenCV alongside OpenNI to extract a hand and then the individual fingers from a depth image generated by the Xtion sensor. When a focus gesture for the hands generator has been performed the hasHand bool is set to true and the code below is run. The hand[] is a float array with the x, y and z coordinates of the hand being tracked.

```
if(hasHand)
    {
        unsigned char shade = 255 - (unsigned char)(hand[2] *  128.0f);
        Scalar color(0, shade, 0);

        vector<Point> handContour;
        getHandContour(depthMat, hand, handContour);
        bool grasp = convexity(handContour) > grabConvexity; //PROBLEM
        int thickness = grasp ? CV_FILLED : 3;
        circle(depthMatBgr, Point(hand[0], hand[1]), 10, color, thickness);

        vector<Point> fingerTips;
        detectFingerTips(handContour, fingerTips, &depthMatBgr);
    }
```

Everything runs fine up until the line I've commented, at which point I receive:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (input array is not a valid matrix) in unknown function, ...
```

I've been stuck with this problem for a while now and I have no idea why I'm getting this. The code for the getHandContour is:

```
bool getHandContour(const Mat &depthMat, const float *v, vector<Point> &handContour) 
{
const int maxHandRadius = 128; // in px
const short handDepthRange = 200; // in mm
const double epsilon = 17.5; // approximation accuracy (maximum distance between    the original hand contour and its approximation)

depth = v[2] * 1000.0f; // hand depth
nearClip = depth - 100; // near clipping plane
farClip = depth + 100; // far clipping plane

static Mat mask(frameSize, CV_8UC1);
mask.setTo(0);

// extract hand region  
circle(mask, Point(v[0], v[1]), maxHandRadius, 255, CV_FILLED);
mask = mask & depthMat > nearClip & depthMat < farClip;

// DEBUG(show mask)
imshow("mask1", mask);

// assume largest contour in hand region to be the hand contour
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
int n = contours.size();
int maxI = -1;
int maxSize = -1;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int size  = contours[i].size();
    if (size > maxSize) {
        maxSize = size;
        maxI = i;
    }
}

bool handContourFound = (maxI >= 0);

if (handContourFound) {
    approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[maxI]), handContour, epsilon, true );
}

return maxI >= 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is enough information for people to help me (kinda new to a lot of this) but any nudges in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to include the convexity() code in this question:

```
double convexity(const vector<Point> &contour) {
Mat contourMat(contour);

vector<int> hull;
convexHull(contourMat, hull);

int n = hull.size();
vector<Point> hullContour;

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    hullContour.push_back(contour[hull[i]]);
}

Mat hullContourMat(hullContour);

return (contourArea(contourMat) / contourArea(hullContourMat));
}
```

Comment: No calls to `OpenCV` occur directly on that line, right?  (`convexity` is not an `OpenCV` function, right?)  Which means somewhere in `convexity` you are calling `OpenCV` and passing in an invalid matrix.  Note that the call to `OpenCV` might be on a different line than you think it is (say in `getHandContour`) if you aren't sufficiently experienced in the quirks of debugging.  The first thing you need to do is find the spot where you actually enter `OpenCV`.  Then attempt to reproduce the error in a stand-alone program.

Comment: You can show convexity() implementation. Seems it expects something like Mat type (which is OpenCV type).

Comment: I've added the convexity() implementation now, sorry it wasn't there in the first place

Comment: I am not sure if this matters in your case, but sometimes (strangely, not always) there are qualified names used like cv::convexHull(handContourMat, hull);. You can compare here - http://lego3d.googlecode.com/svn-history/r130/trunk/kinect_client/SceneDrawer.cpp

Answer (score 0):

I believe approxPolyDP only takes one countour, while you are attempting to pass it the whole list